How to rotate without creating new faces?
I'm new to Blender, just learning basics, but I cant solve this.
Why can I rotate sometimes with vertexes around coming along and sometimes I'm creating new faces?



I am not really sure what you are asking, but maybe you tapped E before R by mistake? E will extrude faces and make new vertices that you then rotate by R by mistake, try to select that face and just move it with G (other way around is to remove duplicated vertices by merging
